# como convertir un array de string en una matriz de numeros

Tags: javascript

Tego esto:

```js
     function Matrix(strArr) {
        
        for(var a=0; a < strArr.length; a++){
            arr += strArr[a].slice('\[').slice('\]').split(/[,]+/g).map(function(item) {
            return parseInt(item, 10);
            });
        }
        return strArr;
        }
    
        console.log(Matrix(["[1, 2]", "[10, 14]"]));
```

me resulta esto:

> undefinedNaN,2NaN,14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function Matrix(strArr) {
 // almacenara nuestro nuevo arreglo
 let arr=[];
 for(let a=0; a < strArr.length; a++)
  // hacemos un parse json del string para convertir a array
  // agregamos el resultado al arr
  arr.push(JSON.parse(strArr[a]));
 // retornamos resultado
 return arr;
}
console.log(Matrix(["[1, 2]", "[10, 14]"]));
```

ahora bien si deseas convertir a arreglo sin dimenciones

```js
function Matrix(strArr) {
 // almacenara nuestro nuevo arreglo
 let arr=[];
 for(let a=0; a < strArr.length; a++)
  // hacemos un parse json del string para convertir a array
  // agregamos el resultado al arr
  arr.push(JSON.parse(strArr[a]));
 // retornamos resultado sin dimenciones
 return arr.flat(1);
}
console.log(Matrix(["[1, 2]", "[10, 14]"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma bastante mas resumida sería:

```js
let arr = ["[1, 2]", "[10, 14]"];

arr = arr.map(e=>JSON.parse(e));

console.log(arr)
```